# MongoDB how to find by index ignore case

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

How can I find document using nickname as index? I don't know is it in upper/lower case.

```
_id: ...
credits: {
  nickname: "test"
  password: "hash"
}
```

Right now I'm trying to do something like this, but unsuccessful.

```
mongo.createIndex(new Document("credits.nickname", "text"), 
 new IndexOptions().name("nickname").unique(true)
  .collation(Collation.builder()
    .locale("simple").caseLevel(false).collationStrength(CollationStrength.PRIMARY)
  .build()))

// null
mongo.collection().find(new Document("credits.nickname", "TEST")).projection(Projections.include("credits"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are looking for something like that https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-case-insensitive/#examples

Also you can consider saving same info with new field name with always lowercase value and making searches against it with lowercased query text.

Comment: Thanks. I solved my problem with

.findOne(new Document("$text", new Document("$search", "TeSt")));